# Android MQTT Client SSL Handshake Exception: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently trying to connect to an MQTT broker via SSL/TLS from an Android client. For this, I have a combination of three keys: crt, key, and ca. The ca key is self-signed and not trusted by default.

This is the certificate information:

```
Subject iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
Common names    iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
Alternative names   iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
Serial Number   3a6e35afb2dd3f43908e40d10c3a01f66dfd79f0
Valid from  Mon, 29 May 2023 08:24:00 UTC
Valid until Tue, 28 May 2024 08:24:00 UTC (expires in 10 months and 2 days)
Issuer  iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
Signature algorithm SHA512withRSA
```

I am using the Paho MQTT library in Android. Here is the code that I am using to connect and publish:

```java
package com.dakatech.daka_ap;

import android.content.Context;
import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class MqttClient {

    private static final String brokerUrl = "ssl://iot.fr-par.scw.cloud:8883";
    private static final String clientId = "AndroidClient";
    private static final String topic = "your/topic";
    private final Context context; // Initialized in constructor

    public MqttClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void connectAndPublish() {
        try {

            // Créer le SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext;
            try {
                sslContext = getSslContext(context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(context, brokerUrl, clientId);
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

            client.connect(options, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // Connecté, publier un message
                    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage("Hello, world!".getBytes());
                    message.setQos(1);
                    try {
                        client.publish(topic, message);
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    // La connexion a échoué
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Gérer l'erreur
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        private SSLContext getSslContext(Context context) throws Exception {
            // Charger le certificat CA
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca);
            X509Certificate caCertificate;
            try {
                caCertificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", caCertificate);

            // Créer un TrustManager qui fait confiance au keystore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // Charger le keystore du client
            KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            try (InputStream keyStoreInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client)) {
                clientKeyStore.load(keyStoreInput, "poplpopl".toCharArray());
            }

            // Créer un KeyManager à partir du keystore du client
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(clientKeyStore, "poplpopl".toCharArray());

            // Créer un SSLContext qui utilise notre TrustManager et KeyManager
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            return sslContext;
        }
}
```

However, I am getting an SSLHandshakeException with the message `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`. It's like Java is not reading the CA certificate.

I defined a network-security-config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <!-- Trust certificates in raw resource directories -->
            <certificates src="@raw/ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

And I linked it in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<application
...
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
...>
```

The keys are correctly placed in the src/raw directory.

Despite all these, the issue persists. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

ps: connection is working with openssl on linux:

```
openssl s_client -connect iot.fr-par.scw.cloud:8883 -cert crt.pem -key key.pem -CAfile ca.pem
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = scaleway.com, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = iot-hub, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = iot-hub, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
   i:C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = scaleway.com, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA512
   v:NotBefore: May 29 08:24:00 2023 GMT; NotAfter: May 28 08:24:00 2024 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF9zCCA9+gAwIBAgIUOm41r7LdP0OQjkDRDDoB9m39efAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEN
BQAwZjELMAkGA1UEBhMCRlIxDjAMBgNVBAcTBVBhcmlzMREwDwYDVQQKEwhTY2Fs
ZXdheTEVMBMGA1UECxMMc2NhbGV3YXkuY29tMR0wGwYDVQQDExRpb3QuZnItcGFy
LnNjdy5jbG91ZDAeFw0yMzA1MjkwODI0MDBaFw0yNDA1MjgwODI0MDBaMGExCzAJ
BgNVBAYTAkZSMQ4wDAYDVQQHEwVQYXJpczERMA8GA1UEChMIU2NhbGV3YXkxEDAO
BgNVBAsTB2lvdC1odWIxHTAbBgNVBAMTFGlvdC5mci1wYXIuc2N3LmNsb3VkMIIC
IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA8jTXyhDM0NttOng6BwuMIgyV
7B/lO4j4lOUiCet3bJmMPzh/stL+jKFmJ9oSI9ShpD9q/DIoAMrWMC1mzcU0CR/6
yJ7UbT8U9Kjnvnp5KY3UXBiCvBU8GSbZHc4gsLc8Q5dGNw4P7AAXcQyBviDpSNy9
dUxkbjjAPD/KQJmiru8r/eRSick1N9WMnSW938lxeOxVpa5bpUUDj/PGL6G1gh/g
04IV1oc3RyhJ0DaAuA/3HokCJnGgXYewkJLrabPbOn6t4qmrQqKzd/xSae1/98bS
+liXuAnoZQkLv2N9uUyJHefEnn3y+YRkat2L+9vUpfXzhLjBIphDRbzAlzSTGRbD
T7TAuQdKLbIpb+WpgGVmRvcOBpxRy7i0op1z+ypXsuSZHtlYB4pAUwSb1D6k0Bqp
MAdTWY2/IlQ6ECfZp3LvrQUhzZd6vv9firMkEhPzWUqck0/8G3UTUg5eikcYhBKS
QUEuWe6qKfzmdtXZSIWRVdyA1TiVNCVG7eqB1DgHRBNFrIPPSfapH7XXj1TGu/XS
LR/cJ8d3STnt+WaQVm+tgRlblT6EYhcDpwrKbqip3DgVJ2rPAVqVGWkihjz5PPMr
IvthxiSOqCTzLelxgna/lKD13b8d/2K/uMycFUmDjRwfeLXAMjzi78KBjewhPC6u
MqCV31n+AnmQWxb6/U8CAwEAAaOBoTCBnjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYDVR0l
BBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0OBBYE
FA3Y5ZxN0W/maIAggwgsxC6J75XfMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFAJBBDKX4egU/YknRFDp
ARE2glxdMB8GA1UdEQQYMBaCFGlvdC5mci1wYXIuc2N3LmNsb3VkMA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBDQUAA4ICAQAGuNWUzvA5P7ZtQJJ/vyIxT12F2NL9gdklwJtVdaA4iLGXaHtv
bFZbVllWBTB8eXOAE0h1gvWGUmcQ6Y5W+9SZYFKnXl3iA3tn9sbMUuPW70Ljbp9B
jrg4ABUrmyuYXNTSUcKbfXk8xLIvckzkr/2kEPixv//T/wZnIhYKSoIgpBKaw4n7
uE7shtR1A/tOc3WLlmI+8419GuI0zzbBA5kzao9Ch2zBBFjciWicGxSLiDidJWlS
NmJx7ZGRgFYcG/anAJvUYDTboVH2KJ/PZ51Q8sUa+uph5q8N2vgT/8sNNBf9MYfn
iq72p9F9ippOxM4dVYAEXIAk3mehtS19yuLAF3t5zjSMuhbrez49H5FcTuJ+Gg8Q
6+p9/upZmB3QqrBh2sIOMYWW9qEbXbw2lKSsRm6/wnH7F3E5iGPzSLkJGgsyGTZ1
k1setqUIjLhJlha6Wt0p/CrgRpBvNWCam0/0ZASamgVy7vV7Ru4vIzOGvE8FR4PI
0b4M5uYdNCFnYYE6HL3i+/dtOi4I1GXH50iSTGztBARhII+FBf+Mh4Gft15+WzG5
RSaCRz1YMos6mEUqKxPzirLQeoLE0jDInTGm05QHMURK1BET2h0UgsrVqbLDMXXt
fAOljTL0CMWtFgQYWC+aWpgjTU8oFmj26AwJA2bK6TJFuWL477ZuJObpdA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = iot-hub, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
issuer=C = FR, L = Paris, O = Scaleway, OU = scaleway.com, CN = iot.fr-par.scw.cloud
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:Ed25519:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:Ed25519:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2394 bytes and written 1827 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Server public key is 4096 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Session-ID: 782BFAB969087DF319705E617BA121BF178F81CA4E14CA86B6467FEC26BC258E
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 4F87F4BDB1D3088B43806BF98D7C0224852773F07D565BCBAD1109D02569EBCB
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 604800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - ec 2a d3 9c b4 2b f9 67-5f 18 2b 06 8e 78 21 59   .*...+.g_.+..x!Y
    0010 - 60 56 f3 27 e3 ea 65 a2-0c f4 f3 cc 4e e1 0f c4   `V.'..e.....N...
    0020 - be 58 36 a4 ca 67 25 ab-69 ae aa b0 62 aa 87 aa   .X6..g%.i...b...
    0030 - e8 de 72 f5 e8 00 b8 90-66 cc b3 08 56 9b e6 59   ..r.....f...V..Y
    0040 - 24 2e a5 0a 92 7c e2 32-6d 59 f4 62 42 bb 89 12   $....|.2mY.bB...
    0050 - e8 b9 8b b0 06 8a 31 14-92 06 ee 09 6e 41 3f ba   ......1.....nA?.
    0060 - 83 79 8c f5 f7 4d 16 5a-f8 6e 83 f3 45 ce d4 ee   .y...M.Z.n..E...
    0070 - 51 97 68 04 e0 ea ab 70-e8 a2 df b6 15 dd a1 dc   Q.h....p........
    0080 - 0c 05 40 76 0d 39 1b 4e-d0 45 39 be 82 0a ad ce   ..@v.9.N.E9.....
    0090 - bf 70 62 02 f6 28 e0 cc-ca 2c c1 bb f2 d1 7e 4a   .pb..(...,....~J
    00a0 - 84 31 61 22 e3 3d c3 a7-d6 26 9d d2 c4 49 a9 8e   .1a".=...&...I..
    00b0 - 26 12 e1 92 70 39 b1 12-90 4a db 58 0b 6a f2 83   &...p9...J.X.j..
    00c0 - 18 5c 1d 23 96 63 6c a4-91 33 85 b5 82 62 37 3d   .\.#.cl..3...b7=
    00d0 - 3d 4c 54 cb b7 b2 a9 20-d5 f3 ca 67 82 80 cc 5e   =LT.... ...g...^
    00e0 - af 5d 05 62 da c5 d4 02-4f 18 14 ac b8 b7 c3 5d   .].b....O......]
    00f0 - cb cb 2d 06 34 f3 83 fc-ec 09 d2 73 31 b6 7e 95   ..-.4......s1.~.
    0100 - 78 ea 84 76 9c d4 70 6a-6f 22 c4 74 ac e5 39 40   x..v..pjo".t..9@
    0110 - 99 ee 04 42 ff 6b 36 53-6a 4b 0a 50 38 4f af a2   ...B.k6SjK.P8O..
    0120 - 5a e5 df 1c 5e df 45 e0-b6 49 b3 6d f4 12 c2 13   Z...^.E..I.m....
    0130 - 20 af d4 3d 2b c2 77 f0-42 36 ae 40 44 c4 f8 6a    ..=+.w.B6.@D..j
    0140 - 51 22 03 82 77 a5 11 2a-53 99 72 4f 0e a6 8f 8f   Q"..w..*S.rO....
    0150 - 57 04 cc f2 43 3d b8 dc-5a 2e 58 a3 4b 91 99 e2   W...C=..Z.X.K...
    0160 - 49 d8 19 6d 30 48 5c c7-3d 5c 8b f4 0f 96 bc d0   I..m0H\.=\......
    0170 - 45 22 80 60 cd ee d5 31-3e c8 0f 17 54 1a 65 64   E".`...1>...T.ed
    0180 - 5c aa f2 91 d2 5e b5 0f-a1 12 e4 33 02 69 66 48   \....^.....3.ifH
    0190 - b4 7f 81 3c 18 78 bc 50-10 2e 29 a3 6b 48 06 cf   ...<.x.P..).kH..
    01a0 - 22 7e 1b 6e b4 73 f6 46-5f 76 0e 57 fb 8a 33 df   "~.n.s.F_v.W..3.
    01b0 - f2 18 b6 e0 3d 5c 55 55-ec 22 a5 8c e3 a9 58 2b   ....=\UU."....X+
    01c0 - ed c3 ec db 50 f3 9d 37-d2 c1 3b ae 45 c2 2e d3   ....P..7..;.E...
    01d0 - 7a a6 b8 64 0e 5a 4f 73-c2 6d 07 f0 43 ef 92 4f   z..d.ZOs.m..C..O
    01e0 - 63 4c 25 37 09 71 16 9e-06 b6 66 bf 11 4b 48 ff   cL%7.q....f..KH.
    01f0 - ad 03 5a 1a a6 9e 4e 50-49 97 53 73 a3 ed 19 42   ..Z...NPI.Ss...B
    0200 - 49 eb 71 62 27 dd 06 b6-6f 59 92 20 30 60 8c f7   I.qb'...oY. 0`..
    0210 - 35 ce 9b 14 5a 9f d4 ad-fc 67 06 b4 ab c1 89 78   5...Z....g.....x
    0220 - ff c2 12 9f 62 2b 92 99-14 1e 9d 8e 05 ef 38 3a   ....b+........8:
    0230 - 8e 91 d3 10 0d e8 97 d7-9b a5 f3 19 bc b0 11 e9   ................
    0240 - c1 7b 33 da 79 22 f5 81-33 25 77 8a a3 87 f7 50   .{3.y"..3%w....P
    0250 - 9c 76 49 ca 42 63 5b 53-74 fc 79 22 dd 9e 7a b7   .vI.Bc[St.y"..z.
    0260 - 20 38 ba 4b ab 35 2a da-79 d7 4e d2 51 02 f2 f0    8.K.5*.y.N.Q...
    0270 - 4b 25 00 5a 56 6b 1c 21-6a b6 29 b2 8f 3b 94 30   K%.ZVk.!j.)..;.0
    0280 - df 09 27 c3 79 fb 28 5a-3f 9c df 5f f7 72 a2 35   ..'.y.(Z?.._.r.5
    0290 - 1a 6a c1 54 7d e3 e2 46-9e db 47 f8 8e 28 f3 5b   .j.T}..F..G..(.[
    02a0 - dd a3 09 96 ef 38 64 ad-2d 06 b0 9b 62 a5 02 01   .....8d.-...b...
    02b0 - 53 aa 32 30 fb 1a b6 66-35 48 90 1e d3 20 8a 83   S.20...f5H... ..
    02c0 - 84 f6 04 36 03 59 20 db-d7 7f be 66 42 44 3c a2   ...6.Y ....fBD<.
    02d0 - 52 5b 71 82 86 d1 05 d8-00 b8 c9 af 58 15 4d 68   R[q.........X.Mh
    02e0 - a6 6e 87 a8 08 33 f2 72-41 35 4c 71 db dc 97 3c   .n...3.rA5Lq...<
    02f0 - ff 6e 96 bb 3b 6c fc c2-db 48 93 b2 38 98 40 38   .n..;l...H..8.@8
    0300 - e7 ff 1b 41 1d 3a 32 95-dd 65 37 29 f4 5d ca 17   ...A.:2..e7).]..
    0310 - ea 83 18 ef 1c df c6 5e-33 c7 3f f1 08 87 63 71   .......^3.?...cq
    0320 - 7d 02 db b0 9d 64 59 3f-8f 08 85 13 97 28 82 19   }....dY?.....(..
    0330 - 0c 8f 18 65 d4 93 bf 62-ab b8 27 8a 8b 0e d2 00   ...e...b..'.....
    0340 - 39 f0 ee 34 5d 0b 41 5f-9c 96 c7 11 a3 0a 89 81   9..4].A_........
    0350 - 20 c7 30 f8 b0 ad 35 ca-78 4a d9 cb 15 29 9e 82    .0...5.xJ...)..
    0360 - a4 82 6f 4c c9 19 ab 7d-85 05 4e db 08 23 53 0c   ..oL...}..N..#S.
    0370 - 11 f5 00 48 2b a9 91 d4-66 5a 54 56 1e 2b 15 0a   ...H+...fZTV.+..
    0380 - 17 fe 9f 1e 62 bc b4 d5-c9 68 30 87 a5 61 c6 ee   ....b....h0..a..
    0390 - b8 d7 24 b0 56 17 e9 9c-48 79 3f 6b 7e 8b 37 a4   ..$.V...Hy?k~.7.
    03a0 - 96 48 60 c5 c3 66 d9 12-40 0c fb b2 48 27 54 83   .H`..f..@...H'T.
    03b0 - 9d ec 11 fc d5 a7 d3 be-ec b6 bc c8 b3 28 3e d9   .............(>.
    03c0 - ef 79 77 db bc da 43 6c-f8 22 57 c5 7d 40 ea fd   .yw...Cl."W.}@..
    03d0 - 35 9b 7b a6 6f a4 33 9a-8f 53 5b fb 21 29 f0 eb   5.{.o.3..S[.!)..
    03e0 - c0 72 44 84 d6 75 1e ef-f7 8e 09 45 0d d4 77 6f   .rD..u.....E..wo
    03f0 - 7c 79 25 19 d4 7d fa 10-a1 2f 08 b0 ec e0 03 85   |y%..}.../......
    0400 - f5 3d c5 7c 3a 68 ba 74-ca 54 70 85 d7 8c 4f c9   .=.|:h.t.Tp...O.
    0410 - 61 f3 69 8e a4 d2 fa f5-dc 05 ba 19 09 fd 4b 19   a.i...........K.
    0420 - af a7 93 9c 3b e5 37 38-65 b3 11 19 1b b3 e3 85   ....;.78e.......
    0430 - 01 cc 26 4c e3 7a 30 95-34 d2 98 f3 c0 36 97 54   ..&L.z0.4....6.T
    0440 - 41 f8 1d 24 a1 d2 bc 8a-95 7c f3 07 95 72 06 df   A..$.....|...r..
    0450 - 65 15 08 24 9e 28 fb 00-0b 4f f5 0b 24 41 c2 49   e..$.(...O..$A.I
    0460 - b9 b5 c3 13 ee 28 a8 41-05 7c 0f 5d 57 15 be 91   .....(.A.|.]W...
    0470 - fc c3 42 87 fb a7 ac 79-fc 5f 5a 0c 98 1d 28 db   ..B....y._Z...(.
    0480 - f5 7b 1a 5c 80 f4 09 f3-61 85 89 c7 48 a8 14 c3   .{.\....a...H...
    0490 - 88 d6 ea 84 c4 fa aa 0f-b1 bd 02 da b9 f7 2b 7a   ..............+z
    04a0 - c5 a2 cf e5 64 b2 c7 e2-7f 1a e2 dc 46 e1 41 e5   ....d.......F.A.
    04b0 - 54 9b 80 76 c9 3c d1 a7-56 ed 81 56 ba 29 c4 44   T..v.<..V..V.).D
    04c0 - a4 0e e8 c4 58 48 34 2d-4c 18 3d 9b d8 44 58 67   ....XH4-L.=..DXg
    04d0 - 0d 66 1a 43 d8 ed                                 .f.C..

    Start Time: 1690324588
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
```